# how to change background color of image view randomly in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I want to change background color of image view randomly i don't want to set images by

`[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]];` by this code i want to change background color

```
NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"[UIColor greenColor]",@"[UIColor whiteColor]",@"[UIColor redColor]",nil];

// add all of the images to the scroll view
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) 
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[colorArray objectAtIndex:i-1]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

}
```

Can it is possible? i tried but i get error of [NSCFString CGColor]:. in my application i want to create [like this application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flashlight./id285281827?mt=8). can any body guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing string in your array, store the actual colors objects.

```
NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor greenColor], [UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor redColor], nil];
```

Also, if you're no using ARC, your imageView is leaking.

Comment: thanks dude but do you have any idea about creating [that kind of application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flashlight./id285281827?mt=8)? if yes than it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: That's a pretty open question, If you have specific doubts you could ask here, if not is really difficult to know what's in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you need random colors out of a fixed set of 4 colors, you should store the colors as mentioned in the answer by Ecarrion. Then you could select a random color out of that. If you truly want a random color in a larger set, you could use

```
CGFloat green=(arc4random()%100) *.01;
CGFloat blue=(arc4random()%100) * .01;
CGFloat red=(arc4random()%100) *.01;
UIColor *imageBgColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1];
[imageView setBackgroundColor:imageBgColor];
```

Also your imageView is leaking.

```
//fix after adding as sub view to scroll view
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float red = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
float green = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
float blue = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
[Yourimageview setBackgroundColor:color];
```

Generate a random color R,G,B and set Imagview in Background.